# ADA - How to make screen reader speak out change in counter

Tags: html, angular, wai-aria

[image: This is how the control looks on screen]

The control on screen looks as above. There is a counter in the center. When the user clicks the +sign, the counter is increased by 1 and minus decreases by 1. I want to make the screen reader say 'Counter increased (or decreased)' when the user clicks on +/- sign. Is this possible thru aria tags? I think aria-live and aria-control may be useful here but really do not know how to implement it. Please do not ask me to change the span tags - product is developed and tested - we are trying to make it ADA compatible. We use NVDA to test.

```
<div class="segment">
    <span class="counterDec" data-ng-click="decreaseCounter()" >
       <span class="icon icon-subtract"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="Cnt">{{empCount}}</span>
    <span class="counerInc" data-ng-click="addCounter()">
       <span class="icon icon-add"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this angularJS or angular ?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a screen reader only span (one that is visually hidden from sighted users, but only read out to SR users) with something like this:

```
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  left:-99999px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Pop your screen reader only span somewhere in your code with:

```
<span id="sr-only" aria-live="polite"></span>
```

Then inside your functions `addCounter()` and `decreaseCounter()` inject the state which you want read out to users when the buttons are clicked. For example, inside your `addCounter()` function you could add this:

```
document.getElementById('sr-only').innerHTML = "Counter Increased";
```

That way, when a user clicks your add button, the `addCounter()` function is called, does it's thing, but also injects the text into the `sr-only` span. Because the span is using `aria-live=polite` the screen reader will then read out this text to the user.

Do the same thing for you `decreaseCounter()` function, but with "Counter Decreased" for the injected text.

**Edit:**
Haven't had my morning coffee, oops. If you're using AngularJS I believe you do it like this:

```
var updateSpan = angular.element(document.getElementById("sr-only"));
updateSpan.empty()
updateSpan.append("Counter Increased");
```

Comment: (J. Afarian)This exactly the answer I needed. I use AngularJs.

Comment: How'd you go with implementing it @DavidC?

Comment: Customized your solution for my application. works greatl!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can `blur` and then `focus` to prompt the screen reader:

```
<div class="segment">
    <span class="counterDec" data-ng-click="decreaseCounter()" >
       <span class="icon icon-subtract"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="Cnt" #example>{{empCount}}</span>
    <span class="counerInc" data-ng-click="addCounter()">
       <span class="icon icon-add"></span>
    </span>
 </div>
```

In the component:

```
@ViewChild('example') exampleEl;
addCounter(){
    empCounter++;
    this.exampleEl.nativeElement.blur();        
    this.exampleEl.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Comment: _data-ng-click_  do i have a feel it is not a angular syntax more like angular js ?

Comment: @RahulSingh Copy pasted the supplied html. Assumed Angular 2 due to tag.

Comment: I am still not sure (from the above code) where I should add the texts 'Counter increased' & 'Counter decreased' so that screen reader can speak it out.

Comment: You just need to blur and then refocus the element within the `addCounter()` & `decreaseCounter()` functions